# Why is getting the next 'div' in my jQuery not working?

Tags: jquery, asp.net

I have the following jQuery that *does* find the ASP.NET server control (tested by placing an alert() inside block), but it does not set the height on the next DIV in the DOM using .next(). However if I use straight JS to do the same thing, calling the DIV by ID directly it works fine.

What I am trying to do is not use the hardcoded ID of the DIV in case it changes, and rather walk the DOM to dynamically get to the element and set the height.

So 1st: the HTML source of what I am trying to manipulate:

```
<div id="WebViewer" style="height:100%;width:100%;margin-right: 0px">
   <input name="WebViewerReportReceipt" type="hidden"/>
   <input name="WebViewerViewerType" type="hidden"/>
   <DIV id="WebViewer_controlDiv">
    <iframe src="295769102_1619997395_16141400_2120403583/CacheItem" style="width:100%;height:100%;"></iframe>
   </DIV>
</div>
```

Next the non-working jQuery that I think *should* work:

```
//Using the 'DIV' that is created by the viewer (at runtime), resize it dynamically to fit the window
    var myHeight = $(window).height();
    if ($('#<%=WebViewer.ClientID %>') != null) {                
          $('#<%=WebViewer.ClientID %>').next('div').height(myHeight - 10);
    }
```

And lastly the JS that *does* work, but I would prefer not to access that DIV by a hardcoded ID and use jQuery instead:

```
var myHeight = $(window).height();
//Using the 'DIV' that is created by the viewer (at runtime), resize it dynamically to fit the window
if (document.getElementById('WebViewer_controlDiv') != null) {
    document.getElementById('WebViewer_controlDiv').style.height = myHeight - 10;
}
```

Any ideas on why walking the DOM in jQuery to get the 'next' div and set its height is not working?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm guessing that `$('#<%=WebViewer.ClientID %>')` in your if statement is referring to `<div id="WebViewer"` ?

If so, `next()` will not work as it looks for the next **sibling**, not next **child**

So try something like this:

```
var myHeight = $(window).height();
if ($('#<%=WebViewer.ClientID %> div:first').length) {                
      $('#<%=WebViewer.ClientID %> div:first').height(myHeight - 10);
}
```

Here is a jsfiddle with the running code (slightly modified to work in this context):
http://jsfiddle.net/xT7rx/

*You should use* `.length` *to check if an element exists, rather than* `!= null`

Answer (score 7):

It may be "next" in terms of your HTML, but it is not "next" as far as the DOM is concerned. Rather, it is a *child*.

You probably want something like this:

```
$(element).find('div:first');
```

Note, however, that there are some problems with your code.  For instance, this will always pass:

```
if ($('#<%=WebViewer.ClientID %>') != null) {
```

You need to check the `length` property of the selection instead because even an empty jQuery selection evaluates to the boolean `true`.

Answer (score 1):

jQuery's .next() selector gets the next sibling but I don't think you want that. You'll need the ['parent > child' selector](http://api.jquery.com/child-selector/),  something like

```
$('#<%=WebViewer.ClientID %>' > 'div').height(myHeight - 10);
```